# NO-BREAK SPACE after quick auto-complete double brace PhpStorm

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

In Laravel's Blade Template, the use of double braces `{{ }}` is used quite a lot.

I have a small issue though. PhpStorm will auto complete `{{` to the full `{{}}`

However, as most Laravel developers adds spaces like `{{ route('home') }}`, I quickly type `{{` then add a space.

Normall this would add unicode spaces like `%20` on each side of the cursor after auto completion `{{ CURSOR }}`

However, if I do it too quick, it adds the `%A0` (NO-BREAK-SPACE) character instead and does not add the trailing space, causing the statements inside to fail. `{{ CURSOR}}`

Is there a way, to either fix this permanently - or to default the auto completion of double braces to add the spaces before and after the cursor by default, like it does when typing `{!` (this might be a plugin)

**Edit:**

I figured out that my keyboard (Norwegian) has a slight issue with phpstorm perhaps. I use `Alt Gr+7` to write a open brace. If I do it too quick, `Alt Gr + Space` produces a no-break space. I'm trying to figure out now how to either disable that keybind or some other way of ignoring it.

**Edit2**
It was Ubuntu, see my answer

Comment: BTW -- what's your OS and what IDE version do you use?

Comment: @LazyOne I found a fix, and it was a mix between Ubuntu and my Norwegian keyboard (see my own answer). Might be other people are having the same issue at one point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this was not an issue in PhpStorm at all.
It was an issue with my Norwegian keyboards, <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> and Ubuntu

In ubuntu <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> produces the non-break space character

I disabled this keybind by typing this into my terminal:

`setxkbmap -option "nbsp:none"`